# Are there any anatomy books focusing on etymology?

Tags: anatomy, book-recommendation, etymology

I noticed that I can remember names for a very long time if I now their etymological background, the reason is easy I love etymology, especially when it is connected to mythology. However when I learn anatomy searching for the etymological background consumes too much time.

Are there any books or even preferably searchable online materials focusing of the etymology of anatomical nomenclature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though a little bit outdated looking this from the university of Sydney is pretty good and searchable. 
I find it pretty useful for aiding memorisation or just a quick entertaining read.

[Arnold's Glossary of Anatomy - The University of Sydney](http://www.anatomy.usyd.edu.au/glossary/)